# Ways in Javascript/jQuery/etc to measure time elapsed / trigger events after periods of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple game using HTML5 (Javascript). I want to put time constraints on events. For example, when a player enters a room where the roof is closing in on them, I want to give them some seconds to make a decision before automatically having some other event happen. But, if they make a decision, I don't want the timed function to fire at all.

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: Look into `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` as a starting point. :-)

Comment: You need `setTimeout()`

Comment: You are probably using requestAnimationFrame, so use a class which acts as a Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I like to use a custom Timer class

```
            var Timer = function(callback, delay, autoRun){

                this.running = (autoRun == undefined)?true:autoRun;
                this.completed = false;
                this.delay = delay;
                this.callback = callback;
            };

            Timer.prototype.pause = function() {
                this.running = false;
                return this;
            };

            Timer.prototype.resume = function() {
                this.running = true;
                return this; 
            };

            Timer.prototype.finish = function(){
                      this.running = false;
                      this.completed = true;
                       this.callback();
                       return this;
            };
```

You simply create a new timer, add it to a list of timers that get updated by a fixed amount with your main draw loop (20ms is good). So users don't get penalized if your game is lagging ;)

Ex: 
    var listOfTimers = [];

```
function draw(){
    //Called every frame
    for(var i = 0; i<listOfTimers.length; i++){
        if(listOfTimers[i].running){ 
            listOfTimers[i].delay -= 20;

            if(listOfTimers[i].delay <= 0){
                listOfTimers[i].finish();
        }
    }

    //The rest of your draw logic...
}
```